# Show custom options in Magento products list

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have a bunch of simple products listed on the homepage and I want to display the custom options for each one of them. The custom options are added by me from the admin and they show on the individual product page but I just can't display them on the listing page.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829164/how-to-get-custom-options-programmatically-in-magento/3090783#3090783) but it didn't work for me.
I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean custom product **attributes** and not options? Because options are beign filled by user during purchase.

Comment: No, simple products have custom options, see http://www.mageworx.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/p/r/product_options_2.jpg

Comment: Yes, ofcourse products have custom options. But what exactly you want to display on product listing page? Because custom options don't have predefined values.

Comment: There are plenty of situations where you would conceivably need this, such as filtering clothing by size. Sure, you could make a separate attribute where you highlight which sizes are available, but to streamline it, you could filter by which options are in the select list for the custom option "size". 

I would love to know how to do this, or whether it is possible to add custom options to the filter!

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21039/P45/#t170464

@WebFlakeStudio - Custom options do have predefined values set in the admin. He wants to display them on the product listing page instead of making them click into the product information page and then select the options.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but it turns out that it doesn't work with somple products.