# Magento - Query for Product Options

Tags: magento, controller

I want to write a controller that finds the different options for a given product (eg. Large, Medium, Small, Red, Blue etc...).

Can anyone show me the code I would write into my controller?

**Additional details**

I'm getting closer, but I still can't figure it out.  Here's the code I wrote in my controller

```
$db = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
print_r($db->getOptions());  // returns an empty array
echo $db->getHasOptions();  // echos 1
```

But when I do the print_r() on the second line, the getOptions returns an empty array.  The third line echo's the value 1, which means there SHOULD BE options.

**Additional Details**
I tried clockworkgeek's solution of `$db->getProductOptions()`, that returned nothing.  I tried `$db->getProductOptionsCollection()`, and got this output

```
Array
(
    [totalRecords] => 0
    [items] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What's wrong with my code such that it is not returning the allowable product options?

Comment: If `$db` is a `catalog/product` model, why are you using `$db->getProduct()`? Shouldn't `$db` already be the product?

Comment: Whoops, that was a typing mistake. I corrected it to just `$db->getOptions()`. My problem remains unsolved. I don't understand why I get the results above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `getOptions()` please try `getCustomOptions()` or `getProductOptionsCollection()` or `getProductOptionsCollection()->load()`.

**Edit**
I tried this on a product I knew had options.

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
foreach ($product->getProductOptions() as $option) {
    print_r($option->debug());
}
```

And got something like this:

```
Array
(
    [option_id] => 37
    [product_id] => 8
    [type] => multidate
    [is_require] => 1
    [sku] => 
    [image_size_x] => 0
    [image_size_y] => 0
    [sort_order] => 1
    [default_title] => Dates
    [title] => Dates
)
```

However, `getOptions()` also worked for me so I don't know what's going on.

**Post-edit**
The confusion was one of semantics. A simple product can have "custom options", they allow creation of a few form fields which are recorded as part of the order. A configurable product uses "associated products" to create a form with conditional fields.

For example you might be selling socks that are large-green, small-green or large-blue - but no small-blue ones. With a simple product you would have a field for large/small and a field for blue/green - which allows the customer to select small-blue and that is wrong.

So to find the component parts of a configurable you might do something like this:

```
if ($product->isConfigurable()) {
    $configurable = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $childProducts = $product->getUsedProducts($product);
    foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
        // You have a $child now
    }
}
```

To find the equivalent of `getOptions()` you need this:

```
if ($product->isConfigurable()) {
    $configurable = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $attributes = $configurable->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
    // $attributes is a Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        // $attribute is a Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute
        print $attribute->getLabel();
    }
}
```

[`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute.html) doesn't have much to reveal about itself.

Comment: getCustomOptions returns nothing.  getProductOptionsCollection() returns a 2 level nested array, with the "items" row containing an empty array.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you confirm if I'm looking at the right thing?  I have a configurable product.  WHen I go to the backend Catalog > Configurable Product > Associated Products, I have listed several associated products: a large, medium and small size.   The solution you're proposing should help me retrieve these options right?

Comment: Ah! Configurable products do not have options, they have associated products. I think the answer is something like `$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts()`.

Comment: Yes! your comment worked!   Can you add your comment to your answer?  Then I'll accept it.  So now I'm wondering what are "options" and how are they used?  It was so mislead this whole time.

Comment: If `$product->isConfigurable()` is true then `$product->getTypeInstance()` is probably an object of [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable.html) and has useful methods such as [`getConfigurableAttributes()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable.html#getConfigurableAttributes).

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is perfect and I solved my problem using it. I was
   trying to display the colors on the list. Here is my solution

```
if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
$configurable = $_product->getTypeInstance();
$childProducts = $configurable->getUsedProducts($_product);

foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
    $sku = $child->getSku();
    $skuarr = explode('-',$sku);
    $col = trim($skuarr[1]);
?>
<span class="colorbar" style="background:<?php echo $col?>;" title="<?php echo $col?>">&nbsp;</span>       

    }
}
```

Comment: curious (can't judge :-) - anything new compared to the earlier answer?