# Magento - Custom options of configurable product do not show in admin

Tags: magento

I have configurable products set up in Magento ver 1.6.2.0 with custom options for colour or design of the item.

On the front end this shows up and works perfectly but when you go to the checkout page you cant see the custom option you selected and also in admin and invoice email it does not show the custom option so it is impossible to complete the order for customer.

You can view an example on our site here:
http://tinyurl.com/cns5sph

If you where to select say a 5 pack in colour green all we see in checkout and in admin is the item name ie. eco multi coloured 5 pack but it does not show the extra custom option of colour.

Even after updating to latest version of Magento ver.1.6.2.0 I still get this problem.

Any ideas..?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Did you create those extra options in the "content management system" of Magento or did you add some code to achieve this?

Magento is really picky in how you create your product line. In most cases you could group the products or set some extra options. In this case you could create one product, the green lantern, and make a new group of products which exists of 5, 10 or more lanterns.

Comment: I created the extra colour / design options under the 'Custom Options' in Magento admin. I'm really stuck as to how to go forward with this as I have already spent so much time creating all the products and assumed that Custom Options would have shown in admin and order? Can you explain a little more what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I have to look for myself before I can answer the question. When I get home, I will try it for myself. This might help: http://support.argoworks.com/entries/195888-how-to-add-options-for-products-in-magento

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, the link you supplied is how I added the custom options and it works fine on the front end but the problem is that when the customer selects the colour option it is not shown in the shopping cart or in admin or invoice emails so there is no way for me to know what colour they require. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this will help find solution but I have also posted in below thread which I think is related:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829164/how-to-get-custom-options-programmatically-in-magento/10108369#10108369