# How to display custom options on frontend other than product detail page?

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am working on magento 1.7 version.
I added some custom options in the products from admin.
Now they are showing on product detail page.But I just want to show on another page.
I mean I have a button on product detail page when i clicked on that button these custom options should be display and after fill that form it should be redirect to add to cart page.
I am using code as below:-

```
$product_id = $_REQUEST['id1'];
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);
$attVal = $product->getOptions();
foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal) {
$optStr .= "<select style='display:block; clear:both;' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";
foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
$optStr .= "<option value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
}
$optStr .= "</select>";
}
echo($optStr );
```

I am doing this process on a `index.phtml` in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\form`.which i created using module creator. 
I am getting getting value of `$product_id`.But when I do `print_r($attVal)` it only shows `array()` on frontend.

Comment: I think this issue is allready answered (see answer 3)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829164/how-to-get-custom-options-programmatically-in-magento

Comment: that was not working for me.Can you suggest me any extention for this?